# Open same page in new tab but new link if in current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html link element.

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

What I want is if user clicks on this link Google opens, however if he right clicks on this and selects open link in new tab, then the current page opens rather than Google.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post your code and provide an example that helps reproduce your situation. Also, what have you tried so far and didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This below code will work for your purpose.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```